# Reading .eml files with Python 3.6 using emaildata 0.3.4

Tags: python, parsing, nlp, eml

I am using python 3.6.1 and I want to read in email files (.eml) for processing. I am using the [emaildata 0.3.4](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/emaildata/0.3.4) package, however whenever I try to import the Text class as in the documentation, I get the module errors:

```
import email
from email.text import Text
>>> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cStringIO'
```

When I tried to correct using [this update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28200366/python-3-4-0-email-package-install-importerror-no-module-named-cstringio), I get the next error relating to `mimetools`

```
>>> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mimetools'
```

Is it possible to use emaildata 0.3.4 with python 3.6 to parse .eml files? Or are there any other packages I can use to parse .eml files? Thanks

Comment: emaildata module has not been updated for over 2 years. It is not compatible with python 3. Consider using the [email](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.html#module-email) package from the standard library.

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri, I'll include an answer here using the email package for completeness.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using the email package, we can read in the .eml files. Then, use the `BytesParser` library to parse the file. Finally, use a `plain` preference (for plain text) with the `get_body()` method, and `get_content()` method to get the raw text of the email.

```
import email
from email import policy
from email.parser import BytesParser
import glob
file_list = glob.glob('*.eml') # returns list of files
with open(file_list[2], 'rb') as fp:  # select a specific email file from the list
    msg = BytesParser(policy=policy.default).parse(fp)
text = msg.get_body(preferencelist=('plain')).get_content()
print(text)  # print the email content
>>> "Hi,
>>> This is an email
>>> Regards,
>>> Mister. E"
```

Granted, this is a simplified example - no mention of HTML or attachments. But it gets done essentially what the question asks and what I want to do.

Here is how you would iterate over several emails and save each as  a plain text file:

```
file_list = glob.glob('*.eml') # returns list of files
for file in file_list:
    with open(file, 'rb') as fp:
        msg = BytesParser(policy=policy.default).parse(fp)
        fnm = os.path.splitext(file)[0] + '.txt'
        txt = msg.get_body(preferencelist=('plain')).get_content()
        with open(fnm, 'w') as f:
            print('Filename:', txt, file = f)
```

Comment: added an edit with a loop over file names, which I guess you had intended to add (feel free to roll back edit).

Comment: is there a way to extract only the sender address ?

Comment: How to find meta-data information (from, sender,cc,subject,etc) and check if any attachment is present?