# How to install packages using pip in Python 3.7 on Windows 10

Tags: python, pip, python-3.7

I am having trouble installing packages for python using pip with python 3.7.3 on windows 10.
[image]

I have installed pip, and used the command "pip install emaildata --user" to get the emaildata package.

I tried different versions of the command, like "py-3.7 install emaildata --user" and the regular old "pip install emaildata", but I keep getting an error:

[image]

It says Microsoft Visual Studio Build Tools is required, but I downloaded that correctly and it didn't make a difference.

Am I using the command prompt incorrectly? I have googled and looked for the answer but I really need your help!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some libraries need to be compiled with appropriate build tools. This is more frustrating in windows. I think python 3.7 needs vstudio build tools 2017: `https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads/`. Make sure you installed the right version and check again.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the definitive answer! :-D  **Emaildata** package has not been updated for a long time and is NOT compatible with python 3.x.  It can only be used with python 2.7.  Use **email** package instead.  No need to install "email", since it is included in the standard Python.

```
# Use import email to start using it from python code.  
import email
email
######## output #########
>>> import email
>>> email
<module 'email' from 'C:\\python\\conda3\\lib\\email\\__init__.py'>
```

See [Reading .eml files with Python 3.6 using emaildata 0.3.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45679331/reading-eml-files-with-python-3-6-using-emaildata-0-3-4) .  Link also has examples of using the **email** library.

> emaildata module has not been updated for over 2 years. It is not compatible with python 3. Consider using the email package from the standard library. – Dmitri Chubarov Aug 14 '17 at 17:19