# Python - How to Pull URLs From EML Files with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, eml

I'm trying to read an EML file and then pull all URLs within it.

I've got two methods: body_to_text() which gets the body from the EML, with either BytesParser or Soup; and find_links() which takes the body and uses a regex to find the URLs.

I've got it working for most samples I've tried, however when using Soup to parse the non-multipart files, I run into a problem when the sample contains end of line equals signs.

```
def body_to_text():
        with open("email.eml", "rb") as email_file:
            email_message = email.message_from_binary_file(email_file)

        if email_message.is_multipart():
            with open(self.email, 'rb') as fp:
                msg = BytesParser(policy=policy.default).parse(fp)

            try:
                body_text = msg.get_body(preferencelist=('plain')).get_content().strip()
            except AttributeError:
                print("No body found")
            else:
                body_text = body_text.replace("\n", "")
                
                if body_text == "":
                    print("No body found")
                else:
                    self.find_links(body_text)

        else:            
            body_html = email_message.get_payload()
            soup = BeautifulSoup(body_html, "lxml")
            find_links(soup)

def find_links(scan_text):
        WEB_URL_REGEX = r"""(?i)\b((?:https?:(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.](?:com|net|org|edu|gov|mil|aero|asia|biz|cat|coop|info|int|jobs|mobi|museum|name|post|pro|tel|travel|xxx|ac|ad|ae|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|as|at|au|aw|ax|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|cr|cs|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|dd|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|ee|eg|eh|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gg|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|im|in|io|iq|ir|is|it|je|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|me|mg|mh|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|nc|ne|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nu|nz|om|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|rs|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|Ja|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|ss|st|su|sv|sx|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tl|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)/)(?:[^\s()<>{}\[\]]+|\([^\s()]*?\([^\s()]+\)[^\s()]*?\)|\([^\s]+?\))+(?:\([^\s()]*?\([^\s()]+\)[^\s()]*?\)|\([^\s]+?\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’])|(?:(?<!@)[a-z0-9]+(?:[.\-][a-z0-9]+)*[.](?:com|net|org|edu|gov|mil|aero|asia|biz|cat|coop|info|int|jobs|mobi|museum|name|post|pro|tel|travel|xxx|ac|ad|ae|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|as|at|au|aw|ax|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|cr|cs|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|dd|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|ee|eg|eh|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gg|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|im|in|io|iq|ir|is|it|je|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|me|mg|mh|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|nc|ne|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nu|nz|om|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|rs|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|Ja|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|ss|st|su|sv|sx|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tl|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)\b/?(?!@)))"""
        links = re.findall(WEB_URL_REGEX, str(scan_text))

        links = list(dict.fromkeys(self.links))

        print(f"{len(self.links)} links found")
        print(links)
```

print(body_html) gives

> ```
> <a href=3D"http://fawper.xyz/corruptly/676197486/trout/gen=
> eralizing/1683814388/upgather/disjoin" style=3D"-webkit-text-size-adjust:no=
> ne;text-decoration:none;"> <font style=3D"-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;fon=
> t-size:15px;
> ```

And print(soup) gives

> ```
> href='3D"http://fawper.xyz/corruptly/676197486/trout/gen=' ne="" style='3D"-webkit-text-size-adjust:no='> <font style='3D"-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;fon=' t-size:15px=""
> ```

So then find_links outputs:

> ```
> 'http://fawper.xyz/corruptly/676197486/trout/gen='
> ```

When I want it to output:

> ```
> 'http://fawper.xyz/corruptly/676197486/trout/generalizing/1683814388/upgather/disjoin'
> ```

I've tried using html.parser and html5lib in place of lxml, but that didn't solve it. Could it be the encoding of the specific email that I'm parsing?

Comment: I haven't worked with EML but I believe the problem is that you can't directly parse it, but you can pull out the individual messages, pull the HTML from those, and then you should be able to parse that HTML.  See this post for some discussion - scroll down a bit and some of the later answers have the extraction code updated for Python 3+ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31392361/how-to-read-eml-file-in-python

Comment: @nigh_anxiety Yeah, that fixed it. Swapped soup block with a part of the pullout method from [lastchancexi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71416428/21936606). Thank you. Should this be marked as a duplicate?

Comment: People would probably argue whether its a duplicate or not both ways.  I'd say no because you were specifically asking about using BS4 to pull out the URLs. 
  Maybe write up an answer showing your code including whatever selector you used for BS4, and referencing  lastchancexi's answer as source for how to pull out pieces of the EML? 
  Someone in the review queue *might* flag it as duplicate later but maybe not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swapping the soup block with a part of [lastchancexi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71416428/21936606), which used the Email module to get its payload based on the content type, gave me the desired output.

```
def body_to_text(self):
        text = ""
        html = ""
        with open(self.email, "rb") as email_file:
            email_message = email.message_from_binary_file(email_file)

        if not email_message.is_multipart():
            content_type = email_message.get_content_type()

            if content_type == "text/plain":
                text += str(email_message.get_payload(decode=True))
                self.find_urls(text)
            elif content_type == "text/html":
                html += str(email_message.get_payload(decode=True))
                self.find_urls(html)
        else:
            with open(self.email, 'rb') as fp:
                msg = BytesParser(policy=policy.default).parse(fp)

            try:
                body_text = msg.get_body(preferencelist=('plain')).get_content().strip()
            except AttributeError:
                print("No body found")
            else:
                body_text = body_text.replace("\n", "")
                
                if body_text == "":
                    print("No body found")
                else:
                    self.find_urls(body_text)
```